# Could a Party Choose Not to Nominate an Incumbent?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election, primaries, nomination

For example, if the Republican party wanted to hold a new primary in 2020 and pick someone other than Trump, is there any specific reason they could or could not do so?

Answer (score 14):

Absolutely, it happens all the time. An incumbent losing to a challenger in their own party's primary election is sometimes called "**getting primaried**".

Search for "getting primaried" or "primaried out", you can find lots of articles and books:

- [Getting Primaried, The Changing Politics of Congressional Primary Challenges](https://www.press.umich.edu/5181079/getting_primaried) by Robert G. Boatright
- [We unlucky few: A look at the incumbents who lost their primaries, 1994-2012](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2014/4/20/1264682/-We-unlucky-few-A-look-at-the-incumbents-who-lost-their-primaries-1994-2012)
- [New progressive PACs warn Democrats to oppose Trump — or get primaried](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/powerpost/wp/2017/02/16/new-progressive-pacs-warn-democrats-to-oppose-trump-or-get-primaried/?utm_term=.54f56fd35e73)

It has happened to several presidential incumbents as well, according to NPR's [When Has A President Been Denied His Party's Nomination?](http://www.npr.org/sections/politicaljunkie/2009/07/a_president_denied_renominatio.html)

- John Tyler, Whig, 1844
- Millard Fillmore, Whig, 1852
- Franklin Pierce, Democrat, 1856
- Andrew Johnson, Democrat, 1868
- Chester Arthur, Republican, 1884

Of these 5, only Pierce was elected prior to his primary loss. The other 4 took their office in other circumstances (death of the prior president).

Comment: Also worth noting that the parties can technically just change their rules and run anyone they want. Would obviously cause a big scandal and very severe repercussions from voters, but technically possible.

Comment: Right. The "traditional" method, of course, is for another candidate to get more votes within whatever primary method has been already established. But primaries/caucuses are pretty much up to the state party to begin with, so yes, they could just change the rules.

Comment: Teddy Roosevelt had a somewhat weird situation as well.  The Republicans probably *should* have primaried Taft in favor of him, but they didn't and it (may have) cost them the WH.

Comment: Just having someone run against the incumbent usually is a sign that there are issues with the president, in general popularity.  Being primaried, whether successful or not, is usually close to a guarantee of change of party in the White House, I believe.